# Changing Standard Name field into auto number

Tags: trigger

```
 trigger AutoNumberProposal on Quote (after insert) {
   if(trigger.isInsert){
     AutoUpdateProposalName.after_insert(trigger.new);
   }
 }
 //////////////////////////////////////////////
 public class AutoUpdateProposalName {

   public static void after_insert(List<Quote> qtelst){

    List<Quote> lstAccUpdate = new List<Quote>();
    for(Quote objAccount: qtelst)
    {
        objAccount.Name = objAccount.Quote_Auto__c ;
        lstAccUpdate.add(objAccount);
    }
    system.debug('---14---'+lstAccUpdate);
    update lstAccUpdate;
  }    

 }
```

Quote_Auto__c is a auto number field.I am getting this exception.
AutoNumberProposal: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only Class.AutoUpdateProposalName.before_insert: line 13, column 1 Trigger.AutoNumberProposal: line 3, column 1

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Right now, your question title and your actual question seem to be talking about two different things. This is a bit confusing, so please strive to make your question titles more relevant to the question that you're asking in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The records in `Trigger.new` are read-only in `after insert` context. If you want to perform DML on them, you must create a new sObject instance by either querying or initializing them yourself, e.g.,

```
lstAccUpdate.add(new Quote(Id = objAccount.Id, Name = objAccount.Quote_Auto__c));
```

Then you'll be able to execute an `update`.